# Find a word in log and extract information from previous lines using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a huge log file containing processing of different messages.
Below is a sample:

```
    2017-11-21 11:35:35.288 INFO  [bwEngThread:In-Memory Process Worker-2] i.l.C.NotificaArticolo.PubToKafka - INFO Articolo Main
    TrackingID= 
    ObjectType= HADOOP
    BusinessID= ASTRA-AMDISB-VL-FIRST_bw0a103_bw0a103

   Timestamp: 2017-11-21T11:35:35.265+01:00
  ApplicationKeys:
    []
    [ASTRA-AMDISB-VL-FIRST]
    [ID:EMS-SERVER-ESB.3E3A59E0A8AAE3939:99]
  ApplicationProperties:

  Message: [] START - ID: ID:EMS-SERVER-ESB.3E3A59E0A8AAE3939:99-C4_Kafka.NotificaArticolo.PubToKafka - easymaster_hadoop.notificaarticolo.pubtokafka.module.ReceiverArticolo RICEVUTA NUOVA NOTIFICA
```

I want to extract timestamp on the first line :2017-11-21 11:35:35.288
based on match on last line : START

I am able to find word START as shown below :

```
    ArrayList words = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bSTART\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] words1 = strLine.split(",");
        words.addAll(Arrays.asList(words1));
    }

    System.out.println("WORDS LENGTH:" + words.size());
    for (String word : (ArrayList<String>) words) {
        // System.out.println(word);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(word);
        if (m.find()) {
            count++;
            System.out.println("Found : " + count);
        }
    }
```

Please help me on how to extract the `timestamp(2017-11-21 11:35:35.288)` based on match "START".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pattern matcher in dot all mode:

```
String log;
String pattern = "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3})";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern + ".*?START", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = regex.matcher(log);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Follow the link below for a demo which shows that the above pattern does capture the first timestamps from each block.

### Demo